# What can I use in C instead of "string" from C++

Tags: c++, c, string

I've started doing a card game in C but I couldn't find anything instead of `string` which obviously is not used in C. Here's some code where this becomes an obstacle:

```
struct cards {
    string index;
    string colour;
};

void load_cards(cards deck[MAX_C])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        deck[i].index = '2';
        deck[i += 1].index = "3";
        deck[i += 1].index = "4";
        deck[i += 1].index = "5";
        deck[i += 1].index = "6";
        deck[i += 1].index = "7";
        deck[i += 1].index = "8";
        deck[i += 1].index = "9";
        deck[i += 1].index = "10";
        deck[i += 1].index = "W";
        deck[i += 1].index = "D";
        deck[i += 1].index = "K";
        deck[i += 1].index = "A";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
        deck[j].colour = "T";
    }
    for (int j = 13; j < 26; j++) {
        deck[j].colour = "k";
    }
    for (int j = 26; j < 39; j++) {
        deck[j].colour = "K";
    }
    for (int j = 39; j < 52; j++) {
        deck[j].colour = "P";
    }
    for (int j = 52; j < 56; j++) {
        deck[j].colour = "JR";
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::string` is just a wrapper around `char*`(this is of course simplified), that does automatic allocation and deallocation. You can use `char*` and do the memory management manually.

Comment: If you use nothing but string literals like "JR", you may be able to get away with a `const char *`. Have to see how you use the strings to be sure. Make sure before you go too much further that porting the C++ to C makes sense. There are a quite a few ideological differences between C and C++ that can make a direct port more work than it's worth or a pathetically inefficient C program.

Comment: Wile @Lorand is right, the part (this is of course simplified) is very important. You first have to learn about pointers and memory allocation. That is a tough topic. It cannot be explained here. Lorand, with this warning added, your comment qualifies as an answer. "How exactly?" would be too broad and/or asking for a tutorial, i.e. off-topic.

Comment: @user4581301 Seconded. I even go as far a adding it again. This is not a case of an applicable "two different languages" criticism (though I otherwise often agree with them).

Comment: I wonder why nobody has yet suggested the use of `enum`, which even in C++ would be a much better choice.

Comment: @Leotix, you get this warning because `'2'` is a single character and an integer literal that does not have a storage location, while `"3"` is a string literal which can be assigned to a `char *`.

Comment: These topics will be explained in *any* C text book. Get yourself one and you'll be able to ask for more specific questions.

Comment: Completely different thing is that for a *deck of cards* you do not need *anything like the `string` type of C++!*

Answer (score 1):

`string` is actually a class in C++ and as others have pointed out, it is a wrapper around char array/pointer (which can be used to store a sequence of `chars`).

In C you will have to manually use character array. You can do in 2 ways (primarily):

1. Create a static character array (with sufficient size).
2. Create a character array dynamically using `malloc`. But in this you will have to also free it manually, when the array is no longer needed.

And of course since you are using C, you will have to explicitly/ manually, take care of array overflow conditions, overlapping, null termination etc.

Comment: There may be no need to allocate storage at all. If the strings are unchanging, just have `const` pointers point to the literals.

Comment: Yes. Thank You for pointing it out. There might be such case.